# How to set proper styled component for react if statement using React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on my own project by plan "from Zero to Hero" my friend told me about styled components and I've decided to replace my clear **.css** and move to styled components.

I know how it works in basic. `<MyComponent>` and than `const MyComponent = styled.div` css, css, css

Im strugling about these 2 situations

1. `<div className={color ? 'header header-bg' : 'header'}>` How to code it for styled components? Like `<MyComponent={color ? 'header header-bg' : 'header'}>` But than i dont know what else..
2. In clear styles I have many situations like

   .class1, .class2, .class3 {
   styles
   }

How can I write it in styled components, please? For now, I have 3 times the same code for every class1-3, and that's not good. Also i tried something like `const Class1, Class2 = styled.div` but it doesn't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the props in styled components instead of ternary operators, here the link you can see the example [Add background color conditionally in styled components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531804/add-background-color-conditionally-in-styled-components/72532110#72532110)
and `const Class1, Class2 = styled.div` this will not work, you should have do like this

```
const Class1 = styled.div``
const Class2 = styled.div``
const Class3 = styled.div``
```

And you should learn about the styled components from [this link](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced)